# display all dropdown options from same place

Tags: html, css

once we visit [link](http://siteforexample.com/) on top right, we can see `र - INR`

once we hover on that, we can see dropdown options.

[image]

if we select `Australian $` , it will merge with the 3rd icon.

[image]

But i wanted to display `Australian $` position as same as `र - INR` and whatever option if we select also it should display from same place. I dont want to change the position of `र - INR`

**css**

```
.a123
{
   position: absolute;
    right: -33px;
    top: 18px;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.dropDownMenu a:first-child {
    color: #636363;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="form-language">
    <ul id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Currency') ?>" class="dropDownMenu">
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $selCurrency ?></a>
        <ul>
            <?php echo $lis ?>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML code as well.

Comment: Please reproduce your issue here using code snippets (leave out menu itself, that's not the point).

Comment: @rifa_at_so i updated html code

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti i will try with code snipets.

Comment: Without seeing a working demo I would say that the orange content area is just too small. You can see that the word Australia is longer than the box, it cant fit. So make the orange area bigger.

Comment: @BenRhys-Lewis can you please check demo link & help me to make oranage part bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.a123` change `right:-33px;` to `right:-55px;`.

In `.dropDownMenu li` set `width: 120px;` and `text-align:center;`

Comment: but than `र - INR` will display far away

Comment: Then just do a `text-align:center;`

Comment: i tried this `.a123 {text-align:center; }` but didt worked for me.

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe that's because those tags don't have a width set. Set a width to those li then do the text-align center.

Comment: please check link, i changed as you said.

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe I don't see the `right:-55px` it is still `-33px`.

Comment: please check now. still those options are strating from different places.

Comment: If you want them to be centered use `text-align:center` or if you want all of them to be starting from the same place use `text-align:left`